# How to set all user databases in offline

Tags: sap-ase

Is there a way to set a SAP Sybase ASE database in offline mode or release the devices?
Or unmount the databases?

I am trying to revert a snapshot for one of our databases in the instance but as the processes holds its device; I can't revert it until it's releases the devices.

Regards Tomas

Comment: Have you tried the 'unmount' command?

Comment: My Sybase ASE says that unmount command does not exist

Comment: Ok, can you specify what version and platform you are using?  That's always helpful to include in your question.

Comment: 15.7 but I found the solution.

Comment: It was syntax error; and the isql gave me wrong error message

Answer (score 0):

Re: My Sybase ASE says that unmount command does not exist (in 15.7)

The mount/unmount commands do exist in 15.5+, according to the documentation.

Another solution would be to just shutdown the ASE server, then load the "snapshot" to the sybase devices at the operating system.